# Use ColdFusion to read events over a TCP/IP stream

Tags: coldfusion, asterisk, coldfusion-10

Our new phone system is making use of Asterisk manager API which allows to read events and issue commands over a TCP/IP stream.  My question is.. Is there any way at all to use ColdFusion to read (and in-turn process) the stream of events?  As of now I'm able to view the phone events (incoming calls, transfers, hang-ups etc) via telnet and I'm wondering if it's possible to use a ColdFusion event gateway to process these events as they come over?

Once the initial connection is made (via telnet), I have to submit the following key:values in order to authenticate the connection before the stream begins.

```
Action: login<CRLF>
Username: usr<CRLF>
Secret: abc123<CRLF>
<CRLF>
```

Just wanted to specify that as I'm not sure if that's a deal-breaker with possibly using a web service in this manner.  Also note we are using ColdFusion 10 Enterprise.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think ColdFusion event gateways can be used like that.  They are _listeners_.  I don't think they can initiate a connection. You might be able to use `cfexecute` to invoke telnet on the server.

Comment: Miguel, yea I'm pretty sure that I could use cfexecute but the connection wouldn't stay open to read/process the stream unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old thread, but I am posting this in case it helps the next guy ....

AFAIK, it cannot be done with a standard CF Event Gateway. However, one possibility is using [Asterisk-Java](http://asterisk-java.org/). It is a java library that allows communication with an Asterisk Server. More specifically it Manager interface:

> ... is capable of sending [actions] and receiving [responses] and
>   [events]. It does not add any further functionality but rather
>   provides a Java view to Asterisk's Manager API (freeing you from
>   TCP/IP connection and parsing stuff).

So it can be used to issue commands to the server, and receive events, just like telnet.

**Starter example:**

1. Download the Asterisk-Java jar and load it via this.javaSettings in your Application.cfc
2. Create a [ManagerConnection](https://maven.reucon.com/projects/public/asterisk-java/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/asterisk-java/apidocs/org/asteriskjava/manager/ManagerConnection.html) with the settings for your Asterisk server

   ```
   factory = createObject("java", "org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnectionFactory");
   connection = factory.init( "hostNameOrIP"
                            , portNum
                            , "userName"
                            , "theSecret" ).createManagerConnection();
   ```
3. Create a CFC to act as a listener. It will receive and handle events from Asterisk:

   ```
   component {
       public void function onManagerEvent(any managerEvent)
       {
           // For demo purposes, just output a summary of the event
           WriteLog( text=arguments.managerEvent.toString(), file="AsteriskLog" );
       }
   }
   ```
4. Using a bit of [dynamic proxy magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244067/how-can-i-implement-a-java-interface-from-coldfusion/28248187#28248187), register the CFC with the connection:

   ```
   proxyListener = createDynamicProxy("path.YourCFCListener"
                    , ["org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerEventListener"]);
   connection.addEventListener( proxyListener );
   ```
5. Login to the server to begin receiving events. Setting the appropriate event level: "off", "on" or csv list of available events - "system", "call" and/or "log".

   ```
   connection.login("on");
   ```
6. Run a simple "Ping" test to verify everything is working. Then sleep for a few seconds to allow some events to flow. Then close the connection.

   ```
   action = createObject("java", "org.asteriskjava.manager.action.PingAction").init();
   response = application.connection.sendAction(action);
   writeDump(response.getResponse());      

   // disconnect and stop events
   sleep(4000);
   connection.logoff();
   ```
7. Check the demo log file. It should contain one or more events.

   ```
   "Information","http-bio-8500-exec-4","10/14/16","15:17:19","XXXXX","org.asteriskjava.manager.event.ConnectEvent[dateReceived=Fri Oct 14 15:17:19 CDT 2016,....]"
   ```

**NB:** In a real application, the connection would probably be opened once, in OnApplicationStart, and stored in a persistent scope.
Events would continue to stream as long as the connection remained open. The connection should only be closed when the application 
ends, to halt event streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes-- you'd want to use a Socket Gateway. Ben Nadel has a great writeup about how to do this: [Using Socket Gateways To Communicate Between ColdFusion And Node.js](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2173-Using-Socket-Gateways-To-Communicate-Between-ColdFusion-And-Node-js.htm)

Although he uses Node.js in his example, you should be able to use his guide to set up the Socket Gateway, then handle the data passed to it as you see fit.

Comment: But the ColdFusion gateway is the listener in that article.  Node.js initiates the communcations with the ColdFusion server. How will the ColdFusion gateway initiate the telnet communication with the phone system?

Comment: Ah, apparently I misread your question. I thought that you wanted CF to handle the request, not to send a request.

Comment: Yea I actually did see Ben's article and began creating a rough script using his demo until I too realized it was for a listening app.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a server-side TCP client. I suggest [easySocket](http://cflib.org/index.cfm?event=page.udfbyid&udfid=2001), a simple UDF that allows you to send TCP messages via Coldfusion by utilizing Java sockets.