# How can I implement a Java interface from ColdFusion?

Tags: java, class, interface, coldfusion, delegates

I am working on a ColdFusion app to send Push Notifications via Apple's APNS service. I am using the [notnoop apns java library](http://notnoop.github.io/java-apns/apidocs/index.html). I have successfully sent push notifications using this, but, recently have run into some issues. I want to  use the ApnsDelegate Interface that is provided in order to help debug the issue, but, I do not know how to implement a Java interface in ColdFusion. I am not a Java programmer. Please help.

Update: So far, I've actually written a Java class to implement the interface, but, I cannot figure out how to "bubble" the events to ColdFusion. I've tried logging within the java methods (using log4j), but that's not working either.

I really just need a way to capture when these java methods are called, and to log some info from the arguments being passed.

Comment: Well, since this is an interface, you can mock it. And what do you want to test exactly? Behavior on failure?

Comment: @fge the Interface is a delegate that receives information from Apple. It has three methods - messageSendFailed, messageSent, and connectionClosed. For now, I simply want to know when each of those methods is called - by logging them to a file, etc. - but eventually may use them for more.

Comment: Which version of CF?

Comment: Dunno why this is getting close votes: it's a reasonable question. It's not "too broad", it's asking one precise thing. I suspect the ppl voting to close missed the CFML context to this.

Comment: @Leigh sorry: ColdFusion 8.

Comment: EDIT: @Eric - Okay. It is baked into CF10+. For CF8, it can be done with the CFCProxy in the JavaLoader 1.x+.  I cannot post an example right now, but I remember Mark's docs had a good working example. There is also one in the CF10 docs. See [Creating a Dynamic Proxy](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Enhanced+Java+integration+in+ColdFusion+10). Essentially, the proxy allows you to use a CFC instead of creating a concrete java class.  You just need to create a CFC with the right methods (and signatures) defined in the interface. Then use the CFCProxy to invoke it.

Comment: I agree with @AdamCameron, not sure why the close votes.  But remember, we can vote to reopen as well.  I just did.

Answer (score 4):

(Expanded from comments)

For CF8, it can be done with the JavaLoader's [CFCDynamicProxy](https://github.com/markmandel/JavaLoader/wiki/ColdFusion-Component-Dynamic-Proxy). It is a fantastic feature [Mark Mandel](http://www.compoundtheory.com/) added a while back. Essentially it lets you use a CFC, as if it were a concrete java class. Note, it only applies to interfaces.  (CF10+ contains a rip of the JavaLoader, so the proxy feature is baked in. See [Creating a Dynamic Proxy](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ff9.html) example.).

To use the dynamic proxy, just create a CFC that implements all of the methods defined in the interface. It is important that the function signatures match the methods in the interface (types, access, etcetera). Looking over the [API](http://notnoop.github.io/java-apns/apidocs/index.html), something like this should work.

```
<cfcomponent>
    <!--- Note: If the argument is a java class, use type="any" --->
    <cffunction name="connectionClosed" returntype="void" access="package">
        <cfargument name="DeliveryError" type="any" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="MessageIdentifier" type="numeric" required="true" />

        <!--- do stuff here --->       
    </cffunction>   

    <cffunction name="messageSendFailed" returntype="void" access="package"
            hint="Called when the delivery of the message failed for any reason">
        <cfargument name="message" type="any" required="true" />
        <cfargument name="failedError" type="any" required="true" />

        <!--- do stuff here --->       
    </cffunction>   

    <cffunction name="messageSent" returntype="void" access="package"
            hint="Called when message was successfully sent to the Apple servers">
        <cfargument name="message" type="any" required="true" />

        <!--- do stuff here --->       
    </cffunction>   
</cfcomponent>
```

Then use the dynamic proxy to create an instance of it. You can then use the instance anywhere that expects an `ApnsDelegate` object, just as if it were a concrete class you wrote in java.

```
<cfscript>

   // add the paths of required jars into an array
   paths = [ expandPath("/path/to/cfcdynamicproxy.jar")
            , expandPath("/path/to/the_apns.jar")
           ];

   // MUST load the CF class path in order to use the proxy
   loader = createObject("component", "javaLoader.JavaLoader").init(   
                              loadPaths=paths
                             , loadColdFusionClassPath=true
                       );

   // store "names" of all interfaces the proxy implements
   interfaces = [ "com.notnoop.apns.ApnsDelegate" ];

   // grab reference to proxy class
   proxy = loader.create("com.compoundtheory.coldfusion.cfc.CFCDynamicProxy");

   // finally create the delegate
   delegate = proxy.createInstance( "c:/path/to/YourComponent.cfc"
                          , interfaces );

   // debugging
   writeDump( delegate );

   // .. now pass the delegate into some other java method 
</cfscript>
```

Comment: NB: Though the example creates a new instance of the JavaLoader every time, it is preferable to store it in the server scope instead, to avoid [memory leaks with URLClassLoaders](http://www.compoundtheory.com/using-a-java-urlclassloader-in-cfmx-can-cause-a-memory-leak/)