# Trouble using PubNub's herenow (java object)

Tags: java, coldfusion, pubnub

I have included the Pubnub-4.0.0.jar file into my webroot.
(Pubnub-4.0.0.jar can be downloaded here: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/java/pubnub-java-sdk-v4)

I am trying to get the “HERE NOW” java code into my coldfusion project and am having some trouble in doing so.

The java code is as follows:

```
PNConfiguration pnConfiguration = new PNConfiguration();
pnConfiguration.setSubscribeKey("SubscribeKey")   
PubNub pubnub = new PubNub(pnConfiguration);
pubNub.hereNow()
    .channels(Arrays.asList("ch1", "ch2", "ch3")) // who is present on those channels?
    .includeState(true) // include state with request (false by default)
    .includeUUIDs(true) // if false, only shows occupancy count
    .async(new PNCallback<PNHereNowResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(PNHereNowResult result, PNStatus status) {

        }
});
```

My corresponding Coldfusion code is as follows:

```
<cfobject type="java" class="com.pubnub.api.PNConfiguration" name="objPNConfiguration" >
<cfset PNConfiguration = objPNConfiguration.init() >
<cfset PNConfiguration.setSubscribeKey("SubscribeKey") >
<cfobject type="java" class="com.pubnub.api.PubNub" name="objPubNub" >
<cfset pubnub = objPubNub.init(PNConfiguration) >
<cfset tmp = pubnub.hereNow({channels: "5A4B3B59-FA6A-F22A-404F18EFA8112508"}) >
<cfdump var="#tmp#" >
```

I do not get any errors returned.
I feel the way in which I am calling the “hereNow” method is incorrect or the way in which I am trying to display the results is incorrect.

Can anyone provide any assistance with regards to this?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure by your question if `hereNow` is working in your Java code (assume it is). The PubNub ColdFusion SDK has not been updated in a long time and probably will not be updated (no demand). You are not getting any errors but are you getting anything in your response, like 0 Occupancy? If so, then you just need to enable Presence on your keys in your PubNub Admin Dashboard account.

Comment: I did not know there was a [ColdFusion wrapper](https://github.com/pubnub/pubnub-api/tree/master/coldfusion).  @Steve - are you only asking about the java sdk?

Comment: Yes, I am only asking about the java SDK. I am not getting any errors nor am I getting any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pubnub provided a REST API call for this. https://s3.amazonaws.com/pubnub/sdk/RESTful+Documentation/index.html#presence-here-now-get
Thankyou Pubnub.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `channels` is a method name, not a structure. The same goes for `includeState` and `includeUUIDs`. Call them as chained methods, and pass in the expected parameters.

- `channels()` expects a CF array (ie [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) object).
- `includeState` and `includeUUIDs` expect a simple boolean value.

Something like this should work for the first three (3) methods:

```
<cfscript>
config = createObject("java", "com.pubnub.api.PNConfiguration").init();
config.setSubscribeKey( "SubscribeKey" );
pubNub = createObject("java", "com.pubnub.api.PubNub").init( config );

pubNub.hereNow()
    .channels( ["ch1", "ch2", "ch3"] )
   .includeState( true )
   .includeUUIDs( true )
   .asynch(
      ....
    ) ;
</cfscript>
```

The `.async()` method is a little different in that it expects some type of callback object. Unfortunately, it looks like all of the [callback classes](https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/pubnub/api/callbacks) are [`abstract`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). (I am not sure why. None of the callback classes contain an implementation, so they function more like an [`interface`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).) Sadly, there is no equivalent for `abstract` classes in CF.

Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, nor can they be used with the cool [Dynamic Proxy Feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244067/how-can-i-implement-a-java-interface-from-coldfusion/28248187#28248187) in CF10+. The dynamic proxy is a slick feature which allows you to substitute a CFC, for a custom java class. However, it is only supported for [`interfaces`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). Since `PNCallback` is not an interface, there is really no way to avoid writing a custom java class, that extends `PNCallback`.

```
package your.package.name;

import com.pubnub.api.models.consumer.PNStatus;
import com.pubnub.api.models.consumer.presence.PNHereNowResult ;

 public class YourCallbackClass extends PNCallback<PNHereNowResult> {
    public void onResponse(PNHereNowResult result, PNStatus status) {
        // do something with the result and status here
    }
}
```

After you compile it, add it to the CF class path. Then you can create an instance of your custom class in CF and pass it into the asynch() method:

```
</cfscript>
// .....
yourCallback = createObject("java", "your.package.name.YourCallbackClass").init();
pubNub.hereNow()
    .channels( ["ch1", "ch2", "ch3"] )
   .includeState( true )
   .includeUUIDs( true )
   .asynch( yourCallback );
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Writing my own custom java class was not the solution I was looking for but sounds as though you may be correct. I am going to attempt looking into this as the solution. Thanks for your thoughts on this.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is no equivalent to that java code in CF. I am really not sure why they made the callbacks `abstract`... Since none of them have any code implementation, they really function like interfaces. If they actually *were* interfaces, you could simply use the Dynamic Proxy. However, unless there is a *concrete* class that does what you need (or some other method that does not require an abstract callback), you really cannot avoid a custom java class. Out of curiosity, did you try the CF Rest wrapper? Not sure it still works with the latest version, but it is worth a shot.

Comment: So what did you end up doing? Just curious if you found any alternatives.

Comment: Pubnub provided a REST API call for this. https://s3.amazonaws.com/pubnub/sdk/RESTful+Documentation/index.html#presence-here-now-get

Comment: Okay, definitely better in this case. You should post that and a brief code snippet (if you you have it), as an answer so it is more visible.