# Telnet socket gateway to Coldfusion Event Gateway to Connect to Asterisk AMI

Tags: linux, sockets, coldfusion, asterisk, gateway

I would like my ColdFusion app to be able to record events being streamed via telnet from an Asterisk host through the [Management API](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/The+Asterisk+Manager+TCP+IP+API). The ColdFusion Event gateway can listen to a particular port but cannot initiate a connection itself, so I need a gateway that can initiate a telnet connection to the Asterisk host (on a specified port) and push the streamed events to the ColdFusion server (on a specified port).  I really don't want to reinvent the wheel so are there any utilities out that that can do this?

My terminology may not be correct as I'm not that technical but I hope I've explained the requirement enough!  The 'utility' could reside on a Linux or windows platform.

EDIT:
To connect to and be authenticated by the Asterisk host telnet stream, the following must be sent:

```
Action: login<CRLF>
Username: usr<CRLF>
Secret: abc123<CRLF>
<CRLF>
```

I am aware that a previous question was posted similar to this (but not answered), but I'm happy for a solution outside ColdFusion

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need to do is capture events from the Asterisk server, I would suggest a different approach.

As you seem to be using the Asterisk AMI, take a look [Asterisk-Java](http://asterisk-java.org/). From what I have read, it is a java library that handles the low level socket communication and parsing for you and provides a higher level interface for interacting with an Asterisk server. So it is capable of initiating a connection, capturing events and a lot more.

In theory you could open a connection and register to receive events when the application starts. As long as the connection stays open, the application will receive events from Asterisk. When the application ends, just close the connection to halt the events.

**Initialize Connection**

To simply capture events, start by creating a connection to the Asterisk server. Just supply the proper host and credentials:

```
managerFactory = createObject("java", "org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnectionFactory");
connection = managerFactory.init( hostNameOrIP
                                 , portNum
                                 , userName
                                 , theSecret ).createManagerConnection();
```

**Registering for Events**

In order to receive events, you must first register a [ManagerEventListener](https://maven.reucon.com/projects/public/asterisk-java/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/asterisk-java/apidocs/org/asteriskjava/manager/ManagerEventListener.html#onManagerEvent(org.asteriskjava.manager.event.ManagerEvent)) with the connection. Normally that would require writing a custom java class that implements the proper [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). However, with a bit of [dynamic proxy magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244067/how-can-i-implement-a-java-interface-from-coldfusion/28248187#28248187), you can use a standard CFC instead. Any events from Asterisk will be routed directly to the CFC and can be handled with CF code.

To add a listener, create a CFC with a single function named [onManagerEvent](https://maven.reucon.com/projects/public/asterisk-java/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/asterisk-java/apidocs/org/asteriskjava/manager/ManagerEventListener.html#onManagerEvent(org.asteriskjava.manager.event.ManagerEvent)). This function will be called whenever a registered event occurs on the Asterisk server.

```
// YourCFCListener.cfc
component {
    public void function onManagerEvent(any managerEvent)
    {
        // For demo purposes, just output a summary of the event to a log file
        WriteLog( text=arguments.managerEvent.toString(), file="AsteriskListenerLog" );
    }
}
```

Next create a proxy and register it with the connection.

```
proxyListener = createDynamicProxy("path.YourCFCListener"
      , [ "org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerEventListener"] );
connection.addEventListener( proxyListener );
```

**Receiving Events:**

To start receiving events, login and connect to the server. Use the mask to specify the events you want to receive: `"off"`, `"on"` or a comma delimited list of specific events (ie `"system,call,log"`).

```
// receive ALL events
connection.login("on");
```

Once the connection is open, you will see events written to the demo log file (assuming there is server activity). For a one time test, let the page `sleep()` for a few seconds to allow some events to flow. Then close the connection and stop the events:

```
sleep(4000);
connection.logoff()
```

In a real application, you would probably open the connection once and store it in a persistent scope, like application. Then close it only when the application shuts down.

Looking at the API, there is a LOT more you can do with it. However, the above should provide a basic POC example to get you started with capturing events.

Answer (score 0):

I begin to wonder whether I understand your requirement. You want your application to "initiate a connection to listen to". The CF Socket Gateway may not "initiate" a connection, but it does "have a connection to listen to". Why initiate something you already have? Why is the word "initiate" such a big deal?

In any case, I interpret your requirement, "initiate a telnet connection to a host using a particular port", to essentially mean "connect to a socket on another server". You don't need a whole gateway/redirector machinery for that. You can do it within Coldfusion Socket Gateway's CFC. It takes just 2 or 3 lines of code (search the web for 'reading from and writing to a socket').

So in your final design you will have a connection between two sockets. One on your Coldfusion server, the other on the host server. Communication in the connection is bi-directional. Any number of clients, say 10 000, can then listen on the CF socket for all the messages coming in from the host server.

Comment: I have not used the Socket Gateways, so maybe I am missing something, but I am not following how you envision it working. In this scenario they they need CF to act as the telnet client (essentially) and open a connection to a remote server to kick off the communication and exchange of messages.  The docs state that gateways cannot initiate connections. If so, it seems like that leaves you with two disconnected servers both listening and waiting a *client* to connect. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The English say, "The proof of the pudding is in the eating". I am looking for time, in between work, to code an example of socket-to-socket communication. Or, alternatively, to show why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I eventually took a quick look around and the results seemed to confirm it is not the right tool for this job, ie listener rather than a client.

Comment: I'd still like to use the CF Socket Gateway to receive the stream data but I need that bit in the middle which will connect to the Telnet stream, send authentication data and then forward the stream to the CF EG port - any idea?

Comment: @JamesKnight - While you might be able to rig something together with a a java based telnet client and a Socket Gateway, did you ever take a look at the Asterisk Java library? I mentioned it in an earlier comment (accidentally deleted). From what I have read, it seems like that library is specifically designed for exactly what you are doing, ie interacting with the Asterisk AMI and handles the low level socket stuff for you. I was just about to post an example when I saw noticed your last comment...

Answer (score 0):

I created an instance of the Coldfusion Socket Gateway in the usual manner. See, for example, https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2173-using-socket-gateways-to-communicate-between-coldfusion-and-node-js.htm.

I got the following set-up to work:

1) Content of listener CFC (SocketGatewayListener.cfc):

```
<cfcomponent>

<cffunction name="onIncomingMessage" returntype="struct" output="false">
<cfargument name="cfevent" >
<cfset var msg = {} >

<cfscript>
/* The code within this cfscript represents the proof of concept.     'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is an IP, 1226 an arbitrary port, so the next line connects to an external socket. Make sure it is listening. */
var socket = createobject("java","java.net.Socket").init('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',1226); 
var out = createobject("java","java.io.PrintWriter").init(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
var bufferedWriter = createobject("java","java.io.BufferedWriter").init(out);
/*Send data to external socket */
bufferedWriter.write("Authentication data at #now()#");
bufferedWriter.flush();
</cfscript>

<cfset msg["message"] = cfevent.data.message>

<cfreturn msg>
</cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

2) Content of configuration file (socketGateway.cfg):

```
# The port the socket server listens on.
port=9093
```

3) My system:
Coldfusion 2016
Windows 7 Ultimate

Netcat:
You may use the executable nc.exe to listen to or to send a message to the socket gateway. Once the gateway is running, listen with a DOS command like

```
nc 127.0.0.1 9093
```

Send a message with a command like

```
echo 'my test message' | nc 127.0.0.1 9093
```

Hercules (http://www.hw-group.com/products/hercules/index_en.html):
You may do tests with Hercules GUI utility.  Use its 'TCP Client' to send a message to your socket gateway, and its 'TCP Server' to simulate a socket listening to your gateway from a different host (the IP and port in the code: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, 1226).

Unfortunately, Adobe Coldfusion's socket gateway fails to broadcast, as you would expect, to all sockets that are listening in. You can only get it to reply to the sender of the message. Apparently, this is so by design. Which is surprising. You would expect all listening sockets to receive a message by default. I shall make a feature request to the Coldfusion Team.

I found these two solutions on the web which seem to offer broadcast-to-all functionality and more besides:

https://github.com/nmische/cf-websocket-gateway/tree/java-websocket

https://github.com/softwarezman/cf-socketiogateway

However, I ran into a lot of errors when I tested them on Coldfusion 2016. In the coming days, I shall be adding broadcast-to-all functionality to the SocketGateway Java code that ships with Coldfusion.

Comment: Interesting, but I still do not think this would work. Looks like the code is trying to do that inside onIncomingMessage, which seems like a chicken-and-egg scenario.  Something has to open the initial connection and log into AMI before it streams any events  to onIncomingMessage, but ... that initial connection is not made until onIncomingMessage is called. So that is not going to work. (Not to mention opening a new socket on every message probably is not a good idea anyway).  cont'd

Comment: (Edit -typos) Though it was not detailed in the OP, from what I have read, there is ultimately a *lot* more to working with AMI than just opening a socket (threading, blocking, parsing the responses, etcetera). So IMO they are better off using another tool, such as Asterisk-Java, than trying to roll their own.

Comment: @Leigh, as I said, that was just a proof of concept. Unlike what was said earlier, this shows you can in fact establish a connection to a socket from within the socket gateway and send a message to it. A next step would of course be to check whether a socket exists so as not to recreate it everytime a message comes in. (The gateway holds an ID for all sockets that connect to it). The gateway does not have the responsibility of opening an external socket. I specifically say so. That responsibility lies with the client, the external host. That is the design which the OP has to take or leave.

Comment: BKBK - We are on different wavelengths here ;-) (.. or maybe you are answering a different question?)  If you look at the AMI workflow, it requires that a connection *from* the CF side, *to* the Asterisk server, be established first. Using onIncomingMessage to try and open that initial connection would not work, because that method only fires if you have already established a connection between the two. ie chicken-and-egg scenario. That (and other reasons) is why I said a gateway is not really the right tool for this *specific* job.

Comment: @Leigh, on the contrary, I think we are on the same wavelength! :) You were exploring the integration of AMI, as client with requirements, with Coldfusion's socket gateway. Whereas I was exploring how far the gateway can go, as service provider, to satisfy those requirements. The chicken-and-egg you describe is based on the requirement that the service should "open that initial connection". The gateway can't, and I said so. It expects the client to make the connection. My aim was to explore what the gateway has to offer. Then the OP will know whether or not he can use it for this job. And why.

Comment: Having had a look at Asterisk-Java, I, too, think it is the right tool for the job. After all it is part of the Asterisk Gateway Interface. And the requirement is to connect to the Asterisk Manager. What's in a name? To paraphrase Bill Gates, "Our stuff works best with our stuff".

Answer (score -1):

Use Coldfusion's Socket Gateway. It is in-built and is the *de facto* functionality in Coldfusion to send and to respond to messages using TCP/IP-based protocols such as Telnet,

Comment: As far as I'm aware the ColdFusion Socket Gateway is purely a listening service and cannot 'connect' to streams, it can only listen to streams directed at it.

Comment: Yes, Coldfusion's Socket Gateway does not create connections on the fly. It has just one fixed connection, namely, to the port to which it is configured to listen. Nevertheless, it can send a message to a - possibly, large - number of clients. The clients are connected to the socket gateway, the gateway identifying each by its ID.

Comment: As the CF Socket Gateway cannot provide the functionality I require - i.e. to initiate a connection to listen to, I created this thread.  I'd like to use the CF Socket Gateway, but I will need another gateway/redirector than can initiate a telnet connection to a host using a particular port, send an authentication string and then forward any streamed data to the CF host using the port assigned to the CF Socket Gateway.